# How to match all files in httpd_uri_t handler?

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I'm pretty new to ESP-IDF and I'm writing a simple application learning from the official examples. My goal is to serve HTML pages (along with js, css and other resource files) from SPIFFS.

I changed the partition table to add a storage:

```
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
# Note: if you have increased the bootloader size, make sure to update the offsets to avoid overlap
nvs,      data, nvs,     0x9000,  0x6000,
phy_init, data, phy,     0xf000,  0x1000,
factory,  app,  factory, 0x10000, 1M,
storage,  data, spiffs,  ,        0xF0000,
```

then I put inside my project root a `data` directory with my files. Finally I told CMake to make the data partition image:

```
spiffs_create_partition_image(storage ../data FLASH_IN_PROJECT)
```

Here my code:

```
#include <esp_wifi.h>
#include <esp_event.h>
#include <esp_log.h>
#include <esp_system.h>
#include <nvs_flash.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "esp_eth.h"
#include "esp_vfs.h"
#include "esp_spiffs.h"
#include "protocol_examples_common.h"

#include <esp_https_server.h>
#include "esp_tls.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"

#define FILE_PATH_MAX (ESP_VFS_PATH_MAX + CONFIG_SPIFFS_OBJ_NAME_LEN)
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE   (200*1024) // 200 KB
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE_STR "200KB"
#define SCRATCH_BUFSIZE  8192

struct file_server_data {
    char base_path[ESP_VFS_PATH_MAX + 1];
    char scratch[SCRATCH_BUFSIZE];
};

static const char *TAG = "example";
   
static const char* get_path_from_uri(char *dest, const char *base_path, const char *uri, size_t destsize)
{
    const size_t base_pathlen = strlen(base_path);
    size_t pathlen = strlen(uri);

    const char *quest = strchr(uri, '?');
    if (quest) {
        pathlen = MIN(pathlen, quest - uri);
    }
    const char *hash = strchr(uri, '#');
    if (hash) {
        pathlen = MIN(pathlen, hash - uri);
    }

    if (base_pathlen + pathlen + 1 > destsize) {
        /* Full path string won't fit into destination buffer */
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Construct full path (base + path) */
    strcpy(dest, base_path);
    strlcpy(dest + base_pathlen, uri, pathlen + 1);

    /* Return pointer to path, skipping the base */
    return dest + base_pathlen;
}

#define IS_FILE_EXT(filename, ext) (strcasecmp(&filename[strlen(filename) - sizeof(ext) + 1], ext) == 0)

static esp_err_t set_content_type_from_file(httpd_req_t *req, const char *filename)
{
    if (IS_FILE_EXT(filename, ".pdf")) {
        return httpd_resp_set_type(req, "application/pdf");
    } else if (IS_FILE_EXT(filename, ".html")) {
        return httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
    } else if (IS_FILE_EXT(filename, ".jpeg")) {
        return httpd_resp_set_type(req, "image/jpeg");
    } else if (IS_FILE_EXT(filename, ".ico")) {
        return httpd_resp_set_type(req, "image/x-icon");
    }
    /* This is a limited set only */
    /* For any other type always set as plain text */
    return httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/plain");
}

static esp_err_t download_get_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    char filepath[FILE_PATH_MAX];
    FILE *fd = NULL;
    struct stat file_stat;

    const char *filename = get_path_from_uri(filepath, ((struct file_server_data *)req->user_ctx)->base_path, req->uri, sizeof(filepath));
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%s", filename);

    if (!filename) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Filename is too long");
        /* Respond with 500 Internal Server Error */
        httpd_resp_send_err(req, HTTPD_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Filename too long");
        return ESP_FAIL;
    }

    if (stat(filepath, &file_stat) == -1) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to stat file : %s", filepath);
        /* Respond with 404 Not Found */
        httpd_resp_send_err(req, HTTPD_404_NOT_FOUND, "File does not exist");
        return ESP_FAIL;
    }

    fd = fopen(filepath, "r");
    if (!fd) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to read existing file : %s", filepath);
        /* Respond with 500 Internal Server Error */
        httpd_resp_send_err(req, HTTPD_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Failed to read existing file");
        return ESP_FAIL;
    }

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Sending file : %s (%ld bytes)...", filename, file_stat.st_size);
    set_content_type_from_file(req, filename);

    /* Retrieve the pointer to scratch buffer for temporary storage */
    char *chunk = ((struct file_server_data *)req->user_ctx)->scratch;
    size_t chunksize;
    do {
        /* Read file in chunks into the scratch buffer */
        chunksize = fread(chunk, 1, SCRATCH_BUFSIZE, fd);

        if (chunksize > 0) {
            /* Send the buffer contents as HTTP response chunk */
            if (httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, chunk, chunksize) != ESP_OK) {
                fclose(fd);
                ESP_LOGE(TAG, "File sending failed!");
                /* Abort sending file */
                httpd_resp_sendstr_chunk(req, NULL);
                /* Respond with 500 Internal Server Error */
                httpd_resp_send_err(req, HTTPD_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Failed to send file");
               return ESP_FAIL;
           }
        }

        /* Keep looping till the whole file is sent */
    } while (chunksize != 0);

    /* Close file after sending complete */
    fclose(fd);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "File sending complete");

    /* Respond with an empty chunk to signal HTTP response completion */
#ifdef CONFIG_EXAMPLE_HTTPD_CONN_CLOSE_HEADER
    httpd_resp_set_hdr(req, "Connection", "close");
#endif
    httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, NULL, 0);
    return ESP_OK;
}

static httpd_handle_t start_webserver(void)
{
    const char* base_path = "/data";
    static struct file_server_data *server_data = NULL;

    if (server_data) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "File server already started");
        return ESP_ERR_INVALID_STATE;
    }

    /* Allocate memory for server data */
    server_data = calloc(1, sizeof(struct file_server_data));
    if (!server_data) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to allocate memory for server data");
        return ESP_ERR_NO_MEM;
    }
    strlcpy(server_data->base_path, base_path, sizeof(server_data->base_path));

    httpd_handle_t server = NULL;

    // Start the httpd server
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Starting server");

    httpd_ssl_config_t conf = HTTPD_SSL_CONFIG_DEFAULT();

    extern const unsigned char servercert_start[] asm("_binary_servercert_pem_start");
    extern const unsigned char servercert_end[]   asm("_binary_servercert_pem_end");
    conf.servercert = servercert_start;
    conf.servercert_len = servercert_end - servercert_start;

    extern const unsigned char prvtkey_pem_start[] asm("_binary_prvtkey_pem_start");
    extern const unsigned char prvtkey_pem_end[]   asm("_binary_prvtkey_pem_end");
    conf.prvtkey_pem = prvtkey_pem_start;
    conf.prvtkey_len = prvtkey_pem_end - prvtkey_pem_start;

#if CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ENABLE_HTTPS_USER_CALLBACK
    conf.user_cb = https_server_user_callback;
#endif
    esp_err_t ret = httpd_ssl_start(&server, &conf);
    if (ESP_OK != ret) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Error starting server!");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Set URI handlers
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Registering URI handlers");

    httpd_uri_t file_download = {
        .uri       = "/*",  // Match all URIs of type /path/to/file
        .method    = HTTP_GET,
        .handler   = download_get_handler,
        .user_ctx  = server_data    // Pass server data as context
    };
    ret = httpd_register_uri_handler(server, &file_download);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%u", ret);
    return server;
}

static esp_err_t stop_webserver(httpd_handle_t server)
{
    // Stop the httpd server
    return httpd_ssl_stop(server);
}

static void disconnect_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base,
                               int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
    httpd_handle_t* server = (httpd_handle_t*) arg;
    if (*server) {
        if (stop_webserver(*server) == ESP_OK) {
            *server = NULL;
        } else {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to stop https server");
        }
    }
}

static void connect_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base,
                            int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
    httpd_handle_t* server = (httpd_handle_t*) arg;
    if (*server == NULL) {
        *server = start_webserver();
    }
}

void app_main(void)
{
    static httpd_handle_t server = NULL;

    esp_vfs_spiffs_conf_t conf = {
        .base_path = "/data",
        .partition_label = NULL,
        .max_files = 5,
        .format_if_mount_failed = false
    };

    esp_err_t ret = esp_vfs_spiffs_register(&conf);
    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        if (ret == ESP_FAIL) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to mount or format filesystem");
        } else if (ret == ESP_ERR_NOT_FOUND) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to find SPIFFS partition");
        } else {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to initialize SPIFFS (%s)", esp_err_to_name(ret));
        }
        return;
    }

    size_t total = 0, used = 0;
    ret = esp_spiffs_info(NULL, &total, &used);
    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to get SPIFFS partition information (%s)", esp_err_to_name(ret));
    } else {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Partition size: total: %d, used: %d", total, used);
    }

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_init());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());

    /* Register event handlers to start server when Wi-Fi or Ethernet is connected,
     * and stop server when disconnection happens.
     */

#ifdef CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_WIFI
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP, &connect_handler, &server));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(WIFI_EVENT, WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED, &disconnect_handler, &server));
#endif // CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_WIFI
#ifdef CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_ETHERNET
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_ETH_GOT_IP, &connect_handler, &server));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(ETH_EVENT, ETHERNET_EVENT_DISCONNECTED, &disconnect_handler, &server));
#endif // CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_ETHERNET

    /* This helper function configures Wi-Fi or Ethernet, as selected in menuconfig.
     * Read "Establishing Wi-Fi or Ethernet Connection" section in
     * examples/protocols/README.md for more information about this function.
     */
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(example_connect());
}
```

The issue is about registering the URI handler:

```
httpd_uri_t file_download = {
    .uri       = "/*",  // Match all URIs of type /path/to/file
    .method    = HTTP_GET,
    .handler   = download_get_handler,
    .user_ctx  = server_data    // Pass server data as context
};
```

Using the `"/*"` pattern, no matter the file I request I get the following messages and a 404 is sent to the browser:

```
W (11845) httpd_uri: httpd_uri: URI '/index.html' not found
W (11845) httpd_txrx: httpd_resp_send_err: 404 Not Found - Nothing matches the given URI
```

Please note the warning comes from the `httpd_uri` tag, not from my code (which has `example` as tag). I mean, it did not enter the `download_get_handler` at all.

If I change the pattern to, say, `"/index.html"` it finds the URI, executes the `download_get_handler` function, retrieves the file in the SPIFFS partition and serves it to the browser.

Of course I need a wildcard, since I want to serve *any* file that has no other handlers before (like a specific API that is handled dynamically by the code).

What is the right syntax to match *all* the files below root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons the matching of wildcard is disabled by default.
You have to explicitly enable it:

```
httpd_ssl_config_t config = HTTPD_SSL_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
config.httpd.uri_match_fn = httpd_uri_match_wildcard;
```

This behavior is described [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/esp_http_server.html#_CPPv422httpd_uri_match_func_t) in the documentation.